# SSL Session reuse with SChannel (Windows)

Tags: windows, security, session, ssl, schannel

I have a program that use schannel.dll to make a SSL connection to remote server. But I'd like to disconnect from server often and reconnect without the need to renegotiate shared key again. I know that SSL support this, but don't know how to make it with SChannel.

Can you help me?

Here are some links that can help:

Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374782(VS.85).aspx

SSL session reuse - how to find if supported?: http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-find-out-if-server-supports-ssl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want reconnects to work it's important to use the same
credential handle for each connection. You'll also need to pass in the
same targetname string when calling InitializeSecurityContext. Pretty
much everything else is automatic.