# SSPI Schannel API - Can credential handles be re-used?

Tags: windows, winapi, curl, sspi, schannel

I am currently adding SSPI Schannel API support to libcurl in order to make it possible to use  SSL enabled protocols on Windows without any external dependency, such as OpenSSL.

I already have a working SSL/TLS implementation, but I have a very specific question regarding the re-use of credential handles returned by the function [AcquireCredentialsHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374716.aspx).

Is it correct and possible to re-use SSL/TLS sessions by instead of creating a new handle, re-using an existing one and passing it to [InitializeSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375924.aspx) multiple times?

My work on the Schannel module for libcurl can be found [here](https://github.com/mback2k/curl/compare/schannel), and the experimental version that tries to re-use can be found [here](https://github.com/mback2k/curl/compare/schannel_exp).

I would appreciate any kind of hint or feedback on this one. So, can credential handles be re-used in such a way? And is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and record it here for others:

1. It has been asked before and a first answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905851/ssl-session-reuse-with-schannel-windows).
2. The following information can be found on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378812.aspx):

> Your application obtains credentials by calling the [AcquireCredentialsHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374712.aspx) function, which returns a handle to the requested credentials. Because credentials handles are used to store configuration information, the same handle cannot be used for both client-side and server-side operations. This means that applications that support both client and server connections must obtain a minimum of two credentials handles.

Therefore it can be assumed safe to re-use the same credential handle for multiple connections. And I verified that it indeed makes Schannel re-use the SSL/TLS session. This has been tested on Windows 7 Professional SP1.